# Twiiter4J getDirectMessages() does not work anymore?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4J 2.2.5 (latest, tried other versions).  And can no longer get direct messages to work at all. The same code used to work a while ago.  I assume Twitter changed something.

I'm using

Twitter.getDirectMessages()

and it gives the error below.  No idea why, I can see the direct messages for the account if I login, but always get this error.  The limit error makes no sense, as the account is no where near the limit.

Other API work, like followers/fried/status/etc.

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (http://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364).
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=00919618 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=332bf6ca
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[00919618-332bf6ca], statusCode=403, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remainingHits=107, hourlyLimit=350, resetTimeInSeconds=1328297, secondsUntilReset=1116, resetTime=Fri Feb 03 14:39:45 EST 2012}, version=2.2.2}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:189)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1721)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getDirectMessages(TwitterImpl.java:874)
    at org.pandora.sense.twitter.TwitterDirectMessaging.checkDirectMessages(TwitterDirectMessaging.java:44)
    at org.pandora.sense.twitter.TwitterDirectMessaging.checkProfile(TwitterDirectMessaging.java:35)
    at org.pandora.sense.twitter.Twitter$1.run(Twitter.java:100)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has some time ago changed the rules for direct messages. An app must be especially authorized by the user to access the direct messages.

Did you make sure this is true for you? You may go to the twitter web site and check for the app.

Answer (score 0):

To get the direct message you should try the below code.It works for me.

getDirectMessages(); gives **list** of direct messages. We need to put **for loop** to get text of each message.

```
      List<DirectMessage> messages = twitter.getDirectMessages();
      for (DirectMessage message : messages) 
      {
          System.out.println(message.getText());
      }
```

Let me know if you get any error.